# Babel shorthands has a problem with \bm package

Tags: fonts, babel, bold, shorthands

Using the babel command `\useshorthands{"}` prevents `\bm` package to work normally.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\useshorthands{"}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
    $\Gamma \bm{\Gamma}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Move the `\useshorthands{"}` behind all `\usepackage` lines. Or use `\AtBeginDocument{\useshorthands{"}}`.

Comment: @Ulrike, Thank you indeeed. Solved by `\AtBeginDocument{\useshorthands{"}}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer could you make that an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `\useshorthands{"}` behind all `\usepackage` lines. Or use `\AtBeginDocument{\useshorthands{"}}`